# How to updating certain ROS2 package

Tags: ros, ros2, update

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all:

Currently Ros2 have released the new version which is called Eloquent Elusor.

I found that some packages have updated likes RVIZ and I want to use it at old version which is Dashing.

How should I only update some certain package such as only update RVIZ?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/338702/how-to-updating-certain-ros2-package/) by [jufeng wu](https://answers.ros.org/users/49417/jufeng-wu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2019-11-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to use Dashing all you need to do is following the Dashing specific instructions: https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Dashing/

> How should I only update some certain package such as only update RVIZ?

If you are asking how to use a newer version of `rviz` (e.g. the Eloquent one) with Dashing then the answer is: don't.

There is no guarantee that this will work. Often new ROS distributions come with changes / additions and if `rviz` in Eloquent has been updated for them it won't work with Dashing anymore.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2019-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1